# Google Maps API V3 Duplicated Response when using Directions Service + Directions Renderer

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm experiencing a funny issue when using Google Maps API V3 + Directions Service and Renderer... basically, i have a map showing a location (golf course) and an input box for a user to type an origin point, from which then the API is called to plot a journey path from the origin point to the golf course and show text directions.

While i managed to make most of it work, when i get the text directions they're printed twice on the screen, which is not what is intended since i only want this information displayed/printed once...

Please find the code below :

HTML :

```
<div id="mapDirections">
         <div class="cont" style="font-size:0.9em">
                    <h2>Directions from <span class="from"></span></h2> <a href="" target="_blank" class="print">Print</a>
                    <label>From:</label>&nbsp;<input name="from" id="goDir" type="text"><input type="submit" value="Go!" id="getDir">
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div id="directions"></div>
         </div>
</div>
```

Javascript/jQuery :

```
<script>
function initMap() {
    var myLatLng = {
        lat: <?php echo $row2['latitude']; ?>,
        lng: <?php echo $row2['longitude']; ?>
    };
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('mapSpot');
    var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatLng,
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    var contentString = '<strong><?php echo $row2['name']; ?></strong><br /> Lat: <?php echo $row2['latitude']; ?>/ Long: <?php echo $row2['longitude']; ?>';
    contentString += '<br />';
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions'));
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString,
        maxWidth: 200
    });
    var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
    });

    marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    var onChangeHandler = function() {
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    };

    document.getElementById('getDir').addEventListener('click', onChangeHandler);
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    var myLatLng = {
        lat: <?php echo (float)$row2['latitude']; ?>,
        lng: <?php echo (float)$row2['longitude']; ?>
    };
    var start = document.getElementById('goDir').value;
    var end = myLatLng;
    directionsService.route({
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }, function(response, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
    });
}

$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var element = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var data = element.data("lat").split(',')
    initMap();
});
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=false&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

The website also uses Bootstrap + jQuery and the maps are to be displayed on a Bootstrap Modal window. I can also send the link or attach some screenshots here if anyone would like to have a look at it!

I'd appreciate any help anyone can give! And please don't be too hard on me, this is my first time posting on StackOverflow :)

Thank you all for the help, Best Regards

Comment: How often is `calculateAndDisplayRoute` getting called (stick a console.log in the top of it)?

Comment: Thanks Duncan, really appreciated! Let me iterate through it, perhaps its better:

1)First time modal opens :
calculateAndDisplayRoute is called 0 times

2)First time the "Go!" Button is clicked :
calculateAndDisplayRoute is called 2 times

3)More clicks on the Go! Button (without closing modal) :
calculateAndDisplayRoute is called 2 times

4)Modal gets closed, then opened again, and "Go!" Button is pressed :
calculateAndDisplayRoute is called 3 times

5)Modal is closed for the 2x time, then opened again, and "Go!" Button is pressed :
calculateAndDisplayRoute is called 4 times

- and so on..

Comment: I only see one instance of the directions panel with the [code as posted](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ybghrjLx/). Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Hi @geocodezip , thanks for getting in touch! I believe this issue might be somewhat related with the Bootstrap Modal i'm using, i've tried it before without being on a modal and worked fine too... Is there any way i could share with you the website dev link ?

Comment: Do you have multiple Bootstrap modals defined in the same page, i.e. more than one element that might have the `shown.bs.modal` class applied to it?

Comment: Hi @duncan, thanks for getting back! Only one modal on that page... i'm going to replicate it on a fiddle and post it back here !

Comment: Hi duncan and @geocodezip, here's the fiddle - basically grabbed what geocodezip did previously and added the modal. Unfortunately I can't replicate the issue i'm having...  here's the example - https://jsfiddle.net/zyxrLsoc/1/ . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Might be kinda silly answering my own question, but can also save someone if they're experiencing the same odd issue with Maps and Bootstrap Modals. After some hours of looking around and trying many different ways of achieving the end result, here's a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/b8mk9wj5/1/ - showing how it worked out ::

1) Had to replace .on by .one on the following code bit (lines 60-62 on the fiddle) :

```
       $('#myModal').one('shown.bs.modal', function() {
                        initMap();
        });
```

2) Changed the variable scope of map, directionsDisplay and directionsService to global (lines 12, 15 and 16 on the fiddle) :

```
       map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions); //line 12
       directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(); //line 15
       directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(); //line 16
```

As simple as that. Seems kind of an easy/cheating way of going around it since the button still has some weird behaviour, but at the same time seems to be doing the task in hand.

If anyone finds a more elegant way of doing this, please let me know!

Thank you @duncan and @geocodezip for all the help and time spent on this question.